# How to remove an eventListener inside a class?

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

I have tried both of the following versions but I can't get the `mousemove` eventListener to be removed. I think my limited understanding of scoping inside of classes is causing some confusion, but I'd assume this should work.

```
export class Line extends Graphic {
  constructor() {
    super()
  }

  handleMouseMoveWhileDrawing(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }

  stopDrawing() {
    document.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.stopDrawing)
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.handleMouseMoveWhileDrawing)
  }

  startDrawing() {
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.handleMouseMoveWhileDrawing)
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', this.stopDrawing)
  }
}

new Line().startDrawing()
```

```
export class Line extends Graphic {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.handleMouseMoveWhileDrawing = function(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

  stopDrawing() {
    document.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.stopDrawing)
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.handleMouseMoveWhileDrawing)
  }

  startDrawing() {
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.handleMouseMoveWhileDrawing)
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', this.stopDrawing)
  }
}

new Line().startDrawing()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: problem is `this`

Comment: [This may help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33859264/1377002)

Comment: What exactly is it that doesn't work with your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@epascarello pushed me in the right direction.

When passing a callback to an eventListener the `this` parameter is automatically set to the DOM element that the eventListener is attached to. Therefore `this.handleMouseMoveWhileDrawing` inside the `stopDrawing` method returned `undefined`.

I was able to work around this by using `.bind()` to override the `this` in the `stopDrawing` method:

```
document.addEventListener('mouseup', this.stopDrawing.bind(this))
```